# How to measure the length of a curve in hyperbolic space?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)>0\}$. If we are considering this as hyperbolic space, then we have that the line element $ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ is how we measure the length of a curve in hyperbolic space. The square is what scares me, so I wanted to check to see if my intuition is correct. Thus, say that we have that $z(t):[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$ is a curve in the upper half plane (not necessarily a geodesic, and let us assume that it has continuous partial derivatives or is sufficiently nice so I don't have to worry about taking derivatives), and say we have that $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$. Then I am curious as to measure the arc length of this curve in hyperbolic space. Would the formula be given by
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}{y(t)^2}}dt
$$
If not then how do I measure the length of the curve?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This simplifies to $$\int_0^1 \frac{ds/dt}{y(t)}\,dt,$$ where $ds/dt$ is the Euclidean speed of the curve.

Comment: Thanks, but in your simplification, do I need to care about the $y(t)$ in the denominator?

Comment: Absolutely!!! That's what makes this hyperbolic length instead of Euclidean length.

Comment: And in any particular example, don’t expect the task to be any simpler than doing the same in Euclidean geometry.